# Wrong Date google spread sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm reading a Google Sheet in javascript through Google Drive API.

I have this my function to get the last modification  var dt = file.getLastUpdated() it's give me this result `4/5/2018 8:48:22` NOT my cuurent Time.

I used `var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(file.getLastUpdated() , "GMT", "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");` convert date to grenwich time but still the same issue.
I correct the Time Zone of my google script project to (GMT+01:00) Berlin and still wrong date time

[image]

Comment: What time where you expecting?

Comment: And what time is the Google Sheet set to?

Comment: now it 4/6/2018 3:11PM its give me 2018.04.06 13:11:32.396

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using "CET" in `formatDate()`.

```
Utilities.formatDate(file.getLastUpdated() , "CET", "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

The [`formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) function takes 3 parameters: date, timeZone, and format. If you pass it "GMT", then the date/time will presented in that time zone. Instead, you need to pass it "CET" (for Central European Time) to have time displayed in that time zone.

**EDIT:** A potentially more stable way, that *could* better handle daylight savings (CET vs CEST), is to use `Session.getScriptTimeZone()`. This does *require* that you have your script time zone set, which you did correctly already. (There may not be a difference, as I don't know for sure how this is handled.)

```
Utilities.formatDate(file.getLastUpdated(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

Comment: you are right ! could you explain me what is my issue

Comment: @MokiNex Certainly. I revised my answer to add an explanation. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

check the time zone settings. (File > Spreadsheet Settings) Timezone is the second option.